# h3 polyfill returns empty list

Tags: python, geospatial, geojson, h3

I have two different Polygons

```
poly1 = {'type': 'Polygon',
 'coordinates': [[[37.813318999983238, -122.4089866999972145],
 [ 37.7866302000007224, -122.3805436999997056 ],
 [37.7198061999978478, -122.3544736999993603],
 [ 37.7076131999975672, -122.5123436999983966 ],
 [37.7835871999971715, -122.5247187000021967],
 [37.8151571999998453, -122.4798767000009008]]] }

poly2 = {'type': 'Polygon', 
 'coordinates': [[[394848.932324579, 5815933.130831123], 
 [394848.932324579, 5818765.877144514], 
 [389427.971197729, 5818765.877144514], 
 [389427.971197729, 5815933.130831123], 
 [394848.932324579, 5815933.130831123]]] }
```

When I run

```
hexagons = list(h3.polyfill(poly1, 10))
```

I get

> ['88283095d1fffff', '8828309427fffff', '88283082cbfffff', '8828308251fffff', '88283082abfffff', '88283082ddfffff', '882830820bfffff', '8828309585fffff', '88283082b1fffff', '882830821dfffff', '8828309425fffff', '8828309519fffff', '8828308747fffff', '88283095a1fffff', '8828308211fffff', ...

When I run

```
hexagons = list(h3.polyfill(poly2, 10))
```

I get

> []

Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, h3 only works with the Projection `WGS84` which has the `EPSG 4326`. The coordinates supplied in `poly2` do have another projection! Convert the coordinates, and it runs as expected.